# The Failed build Cordova for Android

Tags: android, cordova, build, cordova-3

The Failed build Cordova for Android.

This is in an attempt to build the application Cordova.

I'm using:
- Java jdk and jre 7 U72
- cordova@4.1.2
- Ant 1.9.4

Bash_profile file is configured with the way the android sdk.

```
MacBook:hello marcelo$ cordova run android

Running command: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/cordova/run 
Buildfile: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /ARQUIVOS/AndroidSDK/Mac

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.2
[gettarget] API level:        8
[gettarget] WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml (10) is higher than the project target API level (8)
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /ARQUIVOS/AndroidSDK/Mac

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.2
[gettarget] API level:        8
[gettarget] WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml (10) is higher than the project target API level (8)
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 93 source files to /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExposedJsApi.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JavascriptInterface
    [javac]   location: package android.webkit
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class WebResourceResponse
    [javac]   location: package android.webkit
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class WebResourceResponse
    [javac]   location: class IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:266: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable KITKAT
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaUriHelper.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExposedJsApi.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @JavascriptInterface
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JavascriptInterface
    [javac]   location: class ExposedJsApi
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExposedJsApi.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @JavascriptInterface
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JavascriptInterface
    [javac]   location: class ExposedJsApi
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExposedJsApi.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @JavascriptInterface
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class JavascriptInterface
    [javac]   location: class ExposedJsApi
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable HONEYCOMB
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]   @Override public void setFixedLengthStreamingMode(long contentLength) {
    [javac]   ^
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:135: error: no suitable constructor found for WebView(Context,AttributeSet,int,boolean)
    [javac]         super(context, attrs, defStyle, privateBrowsing);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]     constructor WebView.WebView(Context,AttributeSet,int) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor WebView.WebView(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor WebView.WebView(Context) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB &&
    [javac]                                                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable HONEYCOMB
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:218: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    [javac]                                                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:230: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    [javac]                                                                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable KITKAT
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:269: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)
    [javac]   location: class WebView
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    [javac]                                                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:298: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable JELLY_BEAN_MR1
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java:830: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)
    [javac]   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaUriHelper.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
    [javac]                                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaUriHelper.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     intent.setSelector(null);
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method setSelector(<null>)
    [javac]   location: variable intent of type Intent
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java:345: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             appView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
    [javac]   location: class View
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         this.aperture = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE);
    [javac]                                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_APERTURE
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         this.exposureTime = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME);
    [javac]                                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         this.gpsAltitude = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE);
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         this.gpsAltitudeRef = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF);
    [javac]                                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         this.iso = inFile.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO);
    [javac]                                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_ISO
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_APERTURE, this.aperture);
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_APERTURE
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME, this.exposureTime);
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE, this.gpsAltitude);
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF, this.gpsAltitudeRef);
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/ExifHelper.java:149: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             this.outFile.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ISO, this.iso);
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable TAG_ISO
    [javac]   location: class ExifInterface
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class WebResourceResponse
    [javac]   location: class IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 return new WebResourceResponse(result.mimeType, "UTF-8", result.inputStream);
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class WebResourceResponse
    [javac]   location: class IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class WebResourceResponse
    [javac]   location: class IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:48: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && "content".equals(uri.getScheme());
    [javac]                                                                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable KITKAT
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             case android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH:
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             case android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1:
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
    [javac]   location: class VERSION_CODES
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 38 errors

BUILD FAILED
/ARQUIVOS/AndroidSDK/Mac/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/ARQUIVOS/AndroidSDK/Mac/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/ARQUIVOS/AndroidSDK/Mac/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

/Path/local/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Path/local/hello/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Path/local/hello/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: can i see your android manifest? TQ

Comment: manifest - http://notepad.cc/jappartu65

Answer (score 2):

Your are using

```
[gettarget] API level:        8
```

But according to [documentation, JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) is available since API level 17. Try to increase the target API level in your project to fix the problem.

Usually you can define the API level in the file AndroidManifest.xml. For example in a line like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Adjust it to your needs, but at least use SdkVersion 17.

Also, install the desired SDK version of Android. You can do so in the Android SDK Manager. It can be started by issueing the command `android` from console.